# C++: How to call member constructor outside the initializer list during object construction?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initializer-list

I want to call a constructor of a member object in the owners constructor, but can not construct the member object in the initializer-list because of dependencies. How can I call the constructer after my initializations? I would really like to not use an init method

Comment: Short of dynamic allocation, there is no way. If you make the member dynamic (`std::unique_ptr<YourClass>`), you can create it in the outer class constructor body. But seriously think about why you're in this situation in the first place.

Comment: If you have such dependencies, you should think again about your design. Is it really needed as part / member in your class hierarchy?

Comment: Delegating constructor might help to reorder dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

**No**.

You cannot call the constructor of a member class outside the initializer list.

PS: Even if you don't call it yourself in the initializer list, then the compiler will do it implicitly.

---

If you cannot call it in the initializer list, and you don't want to use an init-like method, then re-think your design/approach.

Comment: The "no" as answer to a "how" question is somewhat strange ;)

Comment: English is such a poor language @MaxLanghof. But if you have a suggestion about me rephrasing, please let me know.

Comment: The question was about calling constructor of member from base class constructor. How come this answer which talks about base class constructor is correct for this question?

Comment: @mfromla because I made a mistake, updated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options: either use dynamic storage, or placement new.

The first one is obvious (as pointed out in comments, you can use `unique_ptr`). If you want to avoid this, you might try placement new with [`std::aligned_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union) as storage:

```
class SomeClass { ... };

class Owner
{
public:
    Owner()
    {
        m_ptr = new(&m_storage) SomeClass();
    }

    ~Owner()
    {
         m_ptr->~SomeClass();
    } 

private:
    std::aligned_union<0, SomeClass> m_storage;
    SomeClass* m_ptr;
};
```

Note: in this case, you are responsible to calling destructor of the object, as shown above.

You can wrap `m_ptr` with a `unique_ptr` (with a deleted which only calls a destructor) to avoid this:

```
struct DtorDeleter 
{ 
    template<typename T>
    void operator ()(T* ptr) { ptr->~T(); } 
};

std::unique_ptr<SomeClass, DtorDeleter> m_ptr; // no need to call destructor manually
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an union for this (C++11 needed):

```
#include <new>

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int a) { }
};

class Bar {
    public:
        Bar() {
            new(&m_foo) Foo(42); // call the constructor
            // you can use m_foo from this point
        }

        ~Bar() {
            m_foo.~Foo(); // call the destructor
        }

    private:
        union { // anonymous union
            Foo m_foo;
        };
};
```

Note that you need to explicitly call the destructor of `m_foo` at `~Bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

want to call a constructor of a member object in the owners constructor, but can not construct the member object in the initializer-list because of dependencies

You might modify your class to have correct dependency order, and maybe use delegating constructor:

So turning:

```
struct S
{
    S(/*..*/) : /*m1(data), m2(data),*/ data(/*..*/) // Issue, m1, m2 constructed before data
    {
        ComplexData2 data2 = Query();

        m1.init(data, data2.someField1); // Doesn't like init method
        m2.init(data, data2.someField2); // Doesn't like init method
    } 

    Member1 m1; // Cannot be const with init method :/
    Member2 m2; // Cannot be const with init method :/
    ComplexData data;
};
```

into

```
struct S
{
    S(/*..*/) : S(Query() /*, ..*/) {}

// private: // probably private
    S(const ComplexData2& data2 /*, ..*/) :
        data(/*..*/),
        m1(data, data2.someField1),
        m2(data, data2.someField2)
    {
    } 

public:
    ComplexData data; // Before m1, m2 for dependencies.
    /*const*/ Member1 m1; // Can be const
    /*const*/ Member2 m2; // Can be const
};
```